# Stop MixMonitor by AMI in asterisk 1.8

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I start MixMonitor inside AGI and I want to Stop it in another AGI channel.

So inside that AGI I call an AMI to Stop Monitoring the call by Calling StopMonitor Action but this action just stop the Call that monitored via Monitor Command.

I know in asterisk 11 there is stopMixMonitor Action and it worked correctly but I want to know is there anyway to stop MixMonitor of specific channel in asterisk 1.8 or not?

Comment: may be fix by upgrading to asterisk 11

Comment: Yes it will solve the problem but we have a large product with asterisk 1.8, I need a solution for asterisk 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do that:

in AMI there is a Command Action that you can use cli command in it:

```
Action: Command
Command: mixmonitor stop <channel>
```

I hope this question and answer could help some one